# How to make flatlist to load data gradually in RN?

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, flatlist

i have a flatlist which renders so many `renderItem` with data loaded from my custom backend .
the problem is when connection is slow or when i reload so many times , data will not load as expected and the data not render to the screen or the app will crash .
im using a custom hook to fetch data
HttpHook :

```
import { useState, useCallback } from "react";

export const useHttpClient = () => {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState();

  const sendRequest = useCallback(
    async (
      URL,
      method = "GET",
      body = null,
      headers = {},
      credentials = "include"
    ) => {
      setIsLoading(true);
      try {
        const res = await fetch(URL, { method, body, headers, credentials });
        const resData = res.json();

        if (!res.ok) {
          setError(resData.error);
        }
        setIsLoading(false);
        return resData;
      } catch (error) {
        setIsLoading(false);
        setError(error.message);
      }
    },
    []
  );

  const clearError = () => {
    setError(null);
  };
  return { isLoading, error, clearError, sendRequest };
};
```

render item code :

```
const renderItemComponent = ({ item }) => {
  return (
    <Spacer dir="vertical" size="small">
      <RestaurantCard restaurant={item} />
    </Spacer>
  );
};
```

screen code :

```
export const RestaurantsScreen = () => {
  const { isLoading, error, clearError, sendRequest } = useHttpClient();
  const restaurantsContext = useContext(RestaurantsContext);

  const fetchRestaurants = async () => {
    const URL =
      "http://localhost:3000/api/location?lng=37.7749295&lat=-122.4194155";
    const { results } = await sendRequest(URL);
    const mappedResult = results.map((restaurant) => {
      return {
        ...restaurant,
        isOpenNow:
          restaurant.opening_hours && restaurant.opening_hours.open_now,
        isClosedTemporarily:
          restaurant.business_status === "CLOSED_TEMPORARILY",
      };
    });
    const loadedRestaurants = camelize(mappedResult);
    restaurantsContext.restaurants = loadedRestaurants;
    console.log(restaurantsContext.restaurants);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchRestaurants();
  }, []);

  return (
    <SafeArea>
      <SearchContainer>
        <Searchbar placeholder="Search ..." />
      </SearchContainer>
      {isLoading && (
        <Center>
          <Text>Loading Restaurants ... </Text>
        </Center>
      )}
      {isLoading && restaurantsContext.restaurants.length === 0 && (
        <Center>
          <Text>No Restaurants Available</Text>
        </Center>
      )}
      {!isLoading && restaurantsContext.restaurants.length > 0 && (
        <RestaurantList
          data={restaurantsContext.restaurants}
          renderItem={renderItemComponent}
          keyExtractor={(item) => item.name}
          initialNumToRender={3}
        />
      )}
    </SafeArea>
  );
};
```

what i want to do is to load data gradually , so every data that fetched from the server renders to the screen and then render the next one and next one .
how can i do this ?

Answer (score 0):

For big data you should use [FlashList](https://shopify.github.io/flash-list/) instead of FlatList. Also use pagination for data fetching.

Comment: can you explain more ? or is there any good reference or example ?

Comment: FlashList is a package which is way much faster then FlatList so your rendering won't effect the speed of your app

Comment: i dont think this can help me , imagine i have 1000 of data and assume that i dont want to use pagination , with flashlist it still want to load all the data and render it to the screen with a little bit more performance ! what i want to do is to load the first data , render to the screen , then when second data loaded , render it and so on

Answer (score 0):

What do you exactly mean by "data will not load as expected", what exactly doesn't meets your expectations?

FlatList just consumes as much data as you're providing and shows it to you. From what I'm seeing is, that your api call with /api/long={}&lat={} is returning you all the data, which is (assumably) set in your database?

So to have the frontend performance optimized you can just store the data retrieved from your api somewhere and load it to your `data` in steps. Let assume your api returns 30 results and you've saved them in a proper way in your code. Next step to do is to take 6 (or 8 or 10 whatever you desire) of them and put it into the state for the data-attribute of your FlatList (using state or redux etc.) and load more into your data from the 30 results from the event `onEndReached`.

**Important:** The above explained steps were just to optimize your frontend. I think you might have to rewrite your API-Endpoint to load the data step by step, instead of showing it step by step. You don't have to preload 1000 of data lines from your data (hopefully in a database) and shove them through the internet. That is wasting processing / network resources on the backend => You could serve 100 users with 10 lines of data simultaneously in the same time instead of sending one user 1000 lines of data. Okay nearly the same time, you can't do the math like this, but I guess you understood my point here.
For that reason: make your own logic how to load these step by step.

It should not be that difficult to add another query parameter like `?lng=37.7749295&lat=-122.4194155&offset={}` and send back `LIMIT`'ed data from your data-source (offset=0 : LIMIT 10, offset=1: LIMIT offset*10, 10 and so on) right?

Happy coding.